# How does my website know to connect with my Node app?

Tags: node.js, server

If I have Node app running on Heroku and it creates a server and listens to say port 80. How does my website know to interact with the code in my node.js app?

Essentially, I am trying to send an object created on my client side with Ajax to the server-side. How can my node.js app listen for this data, especially in production?

More info:
So I have a static website view with html and css uploaded through shared hosting. I am trying to implement a simple payment system through Stripe using Node.js. So I only have one server for Node and a shared host for my website. My question was how can I connect the two without having to serve the .html files through Node?

Comment: You can directly serve your website from the node server itself.

Comment: Is that absolutely necessary?

Comment: That depends. What do you mean when you say `your website needs to inderact with your node server`? Are your ndoe server and your website two different entities? If that is so, how is your website getting served? Also, if tha tis the case, you can expose API from your node server that you can call from your website server (becuase AJAX requests won't work in this scenario)

Comment: In any case, it is best if you can server your website directly from the node server. :)

Comment: I don't completely understand, can you explain this part "Also, if tha tis the case, you can expose API from your node server that you can call from your website server (becuase AJAX requests won't work in this scenario) "

Comment: Usually, your node.js server IS your website - serves all your files and APIs.  So the fact that you're asking how your website interacts with your node.js app apparently means you have multiple web servers?  You will have to explain what you are actually trying to do before anyone can help you.  Why do you have two web servers?

Comment: So I have a static website view with html and css uploaded through shared hosting. I am trying to implement a simple payment system through Stripe using Node.js. So I only have one server for Node and a shared host for my website. My question was how can I connect the two without having to serve the .html files through Node? @jfriend00

Comment: (Don't worry about the odd downvote. We tend to discourage voting commentary in posts, since people who have voted will already have moved on, and your future readers won't know why someone voted the way they did).

Comment: @Username - please use the "edit" link to put that additional information about the payment system into your question.  That makes it a LOT clearer what you're trying to do.  Your question all by itself (without someone having to read all the comments) should explain the question clearly and with enough detail for people to help.   Also, please explain in your question what you have already tried and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear exactly where you got stuck in setting up your node.js server as pretty much everything you've asked for is explained in many examples on the web.  So, since I don't know where you got stuck, I'll explain conceptually the steps you go through to field an Ajax call from your site:

1. Set up your node.js server listening on a unique port on a host that is in DNS.  Since this is a different server than your website, it will need to either be a different host or a different port (if on the same host).
2. Enable CORS in your node.js app so that your node.js server will let the browser do cross origin requests to it.  There is an NPM module that can make this pretty easy for you.
3. Set up the shell of your node.js web server.  I would personally use Express to make it simpler.
4. Create a request handler in your server for a "post" on a particular route.  This will allow your web server to listen for a specific request.
5. Write the code in that request handler that parses the request and does whatever it is you want to do with the request.

FYI, if the only think you were going to do with your node.js server is use Stripe checkout, then you may be able to write Javascript in your web page that communicates directly with the Strip service without evening having your own node.js server.  It depends upon the details of what you're trying to do.  Some Strip checkout details here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: @Username - see the last paragraph I added to my answer about using Stripe direct from the client without a node.js server.

Comment: This is essentially what I was looking for("Set up your node.js server listening on a unique port on a host that is in DNS.") . I couldn't find a mention of DNS anywhere.

Comment: I'm looking into checkout but I'd like to further understand "unique port on a host that is in DNS". How can I find this value?

Comment: @Username - Your hosting provider generally offers services for DNS or if the hosting provider only provides you with an IP address, then you can get DNS services for the IP address from other providers such as EasyDNS.  How you configure the port depends upon your hosting situation and how the provider works.  If you have your own server all by yourself, then you can probably pick any port (port 80 is the usual default for HTTP requests).  If you are sharing a host, then your hosting provider likely assigns you a port number that you have to use.

Comment: and on the client-side, the ajax posts I do are sent to this port automatically?

Comment: @Username - the default port for an HTTP request is port 80 so that is what is used if no port is specified in the URL.  The default port for HTTPS is port 443 (probably what you would use if this is ecommerce).

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare your routes (assuming you're using something like Express or you've made your own vanilla http server) so when you visit a route it knows to execute whatever function you've tied this too

e.g. `app.get('/', someController);`

knows that whenever somebody visits `/` it will make `someController` execute.

Node directly runs the website through your program its self and knows these things

If I misunderstood let me know

**Reply to comment:**

I'm not quite understanding your question, if you upload your `view` files e.g. your `home.ejs/html/jade` whatever you're using to another server, then upload your `app` to another server, it won't work you'll get 404 not found or something. I'm assuming you came from PHP or something where you have your PHP files and everything is combined like you have your `html/php` in one file and then when you visit your localhost/home.php it works. Node is different you have your `app` which through your server side logic you tell it what view to call, your client side stuff (like your views and css/js and what not) are completely separate from your server side logic, and through your controllers, you tell what function to call what view, e.g.

(assuming you're using express) 
You have this as a controller:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('home');
});
```

then in your `app.js` logic you have:

```
// Your Route
app.use('/', homeController)
```

Then in your `views` you probably have

`home.html/jade/ejs` (extension depending on whatever templating you're using)

now when somebody visits `/` the route see's this and goes ok I need to call the `homeController` and so it does and it's happy, then it gets the content of the function and goes oh it wants to render a view file which then express' function `res.render` will map over your `views` folder until it finds something that resembles whatever you've requested, in this case: `home.html` so it then renders the file and sends the response back to the client,

So in short
`Request > Route > Controller > Function Body > Does whatever you've programmed from there`

Long story short, your client side stuff and your server logic are completely independent from each other

As where with your `PHP` or something, you have your php file

```
<?php

<html>
</html>

?> (i think thats how it goes I haven't done php in a looooonngg time)
```

and then you run apache or whatever and apache will magically route to the `.php` file requested, compile and render it

I hope I answered a little better

Comment: I think its starting to make sense but I have a question. If I have uploaded my website and it's live, and my node app is uploaded on a different server, how does node know to listen to '/foo' of my particular website? do I put the entire url like 'mywebsite.com/registration.html'? wouldn't I be able to put any website's url and just intercept the data?

Comment: I already uploaded my website on shared hosting. Will I have to take it down in order to use Node? Can I just have a separate node file just for a small use case? I have edited and clarified my question a bit